# Half of top panel missing on M10 tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Just noticed that the top panel (clock, signal and battery) is half missing on my M10 tablet. I can still aee things, but only half. How can I restore this so I can see all the items?

Comment: Have checked on my phone (E5) and all is ok on that. The top panel is showing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue some time ago and a reboot resolved it for me. I do not reboot the tablet much, but when I did it worked and the full panel was visable. Give it a reboot and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Smashing that did the trick. Like you i do try not to boot my tablet much as I like to keep the screens open. I think it may be a Launchpad issue though.